# Prolog - parsing a csv file

Tags: csv, prolog, swi-prolog

I try to parse a csv file and extractd a specific coloumn data from each row, I've managed to parse the file to a list of records, but I cannot iterate over the fields of each of the records.
Is their a way to parse the csv file using prolog so that each record of the csv file will itself be a list?

My code:

```
:- use_module(library(csv)).

% main function ,  first parse the file then extracts max total market  
get_rows_data(File,Rows) :-
   csv_read_file(File, Rows, [functor(record), arity(18)]),
   maplist(assert, Rows),
   get_row(Rows).

get_row([]).    
get_row([Head|Tail]) :-
   write('*********************************'),write(Head),
   get_row(Tail).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you are almost there. You only need to convert the record term to a list.

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).
:- use_module(library(csv)).

get_rows_data(File, Lists):-
  csv_read_file(File, Rows, []),
  rows_to_lists(Rows, Lists).

rows_to_lists(Rows, Lists):-
  maplist(row_to_list, Rows, Lists).

row_to_list(Row, List):-
  Row =.. [row|List].
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, I'm not sure why but the output of the program is false. I'm new to prolog and I don't really understand why it didn't work, any clue?

Comment: Either `functor(record)` needs to be `functor(row)`, or `Row =.. [row|List]` needs to be `Row =.. [record|List]`. Or you could just leave the options `[functor(record), arity(18)]` off entirely.

Comment: @lurker Indeed, I've missed those options... Fixed my answer accordingly. Btw, are there any use cases in which the arity option is used as input and not as output?

Comment: I have a more general question in that matter, how can I use a DCG to parse the file instead of the built in csv_read_file() function?
Is that even possible?

Comment: @user2512231 That is indeed possible, Prolog has very good support for DCGs. Have a look at `library(pure_input)`, specifically `phrase_from_file(csv(Rows), CsvFile)`.